# Changing parametres in a function call in R

Tags: r, function

I wrote a function drawing circles. Lines are type ‘solid’ and color is black by default. However, I want they could be changed in a function call. Is it possible?

```
my_func <- function(vector, ...) {
  len <- length(vector)
  m <- max(vector)
# plot
  plot(1, type="n", xlab="", ylab="", xlim=1.2*m*c(-1,1), ylim=1.2*m*c(-1,1), asp = 1)
  circle <- seq(0, 2*pi + 0.1, 0.1)
  sapply(vector, function(x) lines(x*cos(circle), x*sin(circle)))
}

dd <- 1:4
my_func(dd, lines(col = "red", lty="dashed"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way suggested by Waldi will work for those two parameters. However, you will have to add each parameter that you wish to pass manually.

Alternatively, use `do.call` to pass the `...` to the required function - meaning you will be able to pass any of the parameters accepted by `lines`:

```
my_func2 <- function(vector, ...) {
    len <- length(vector)
    m <- max(vector)
    # plot
    plot(1, type = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "", xlim = 1.2 * m * c(-1, 1), ylim = 1.2 * m * c(-1, 1), asp = 1)
    circle <- seq(0, 2 * pi + 0.1, 0.1)
    do.call(
        sapply, 
        list(
            vector, 
            function(x) lines(x*cos(circle), x*sin(circle),
            ...)
        )
    )
}

my_func2(dd, lty = "dashed", col = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! That is what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You could just pass the extra arguments to the function:

```
my_func <- function(vector, col='black',lty='solid') {
  len <- length(vector)
  m <- max(vector)
  # plot
  plot(1, type="n", xlab="", ylab="", xlim=1.2*m*c(-1,1), ylim=1.2*m*c(-1,1), asp = 1)
  circle <- seq(0, 2*pi + 0.1, 0.1)
  sapply(vector, function(x) lines(x*cos(circle), x*sin(circle),col=col,lty=lty))
}

dd <- 1:4
my_func(dd,'red','dashed')
```

[image]